# How to add dynamic app into INSTALLED_APPS?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-middleware

I created a middleware.py file and I try add "suit" into INSTALLED_APPS in this file, I print INSTALLED_APPS despite have in list but no have effect in admin page, style of admin still default.
this is my code in middleware.py file

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models import loading
from django.core import management
from django.shortcuts import redirect
class CustomeAppMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if 'admin' in request.path_info and 'suit' not in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
            print request.path_info
            tmp = ('suit',)+settings.INSTALLED_APPS
            settings.INSTALLED_APPS = tmp
            print settings.INSTALLED_APPS
            loading.cache.loaded = False
            management.call_command('syncdb', interactive=False)
        return response
```

please help me to solve this problem. thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to alter `INSTALLED_APPS` at run time like this.

Django loads the apps once when the server starts. If you alter `INSTALLED_APPS` during a request it's too late for it to have any effect.

Comment: could you help me this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41565974/use-multi-admin-app-in-django

Comment: I want go to admin site with 2 url have style different(suit and grappille). thank you

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that question.